# Why does my Javascript not work when view is rendered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Javascript, which `uses on ready state` in my Rails app.
It should actually react to a link-click, so it's

```
  <%= javascript_tag "$(document).ready(function(){$('#save').click(save);});"%>
```

but when rendering the view, by getting there from another view, it does not work. It only works, when I use `f5` to reload the site.

Do you know why it is like this?

---

## EDIT:

I have added `alert('it works');` to my `$(document).ready(function(){};` but it does not work yet. So the document ready event is not being fired.

---

@[BroiSatse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2336231/broisatse): Yes, I have turbolinks installed. Here are my require parts from my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: $.("document") should be $(document) ??? and what's that ?? $.("link"();) ?? would you think this work???

Comment: Or even `$(document)`.

Comment: You were very fast. I hadn't even time to edit my mistakes in the question.
Have added the code directly from my view.

Comment: Do you have turbolinks installed (check your Gemfile)?

Answer (score 0):

Try modyfining this to

```
$(function(){ console.log("ready fired");$.("link"();));
```

to check if document ready event is being fired

If it's not you will need to find event that does fire and bind functionality to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, would something like this be sufficient. Comment if I'm not understanding the problem.

```
$(document).ready(funtion(){

    $(document).on('click touchstart', '#save', function(){
        save();
    });

    function save(){
        console.log('This Works');
    }

});
```

Comment: I don't think, you are understanding me right. Sorry. There is nothing wrong with my document ready event. 
The Problem is, that it does not fire, when I render the page, but it works, when it's reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a typical issue caused by turbolinks gem. This gem improves website performance by not loading the whole page for each request. The obvious problem is that `$(document).ready` is not triggered when the new page is loaded. To fix it you can change your call to:

```
  <%= javascript_tag "$(document).on('page:load', function(){$('#save').click(save);});
```

However the best way I found to deal with it is to install `jquery-turbolinks` gem as well. Just add

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

to your gemfile, run `bundle install` and modify your application.js file to look sth like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
// ... 
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: I have added jquery-turbolinks to my gemfile, and also edited my application.js, but still it only loads, when I reload my Page.

Comment: Have you restarted the server?

Comment: I'm working on localhost. I had to shutdown my server, in order to tun the bundle install, and then had to restart it. Sooo... yes, I have.

Comment: Hmmm, can you paste your application.js into your question (just the require bits)

Comment: Ok, try moving jquery.turbolinks to be right after jquery (before jquery_ujs)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50786/discussion-between-broisatse-and-user3383458)